# Post-process xcodebuild test output in bamboo

Tags: bamboo, xcodebuild

I am looking for a way to export the test results from a test run with `xcodebuild test ...` to the Atlassian bamboo CI server. This is what I have found so far:

- [ocunit2junit](https://github.com/ciryon/OCUnit2JUnit): Consumes the raw output and produces a set of JUnit `*.xml` files that can be read by the bamboo JUnit reporter. Unfortunately, it's not working well with Xcode 11 (doesn't pick up all the test results). It hasn't been updated in the past eight years which makes it likely that the `xcodebuild` output has changed sufficiently to render the parser fragile.
- [trainer](https://github.com/fastlane-community/trainer): This appears to be a smaller project that uses the `xcresults` file. The last update is 13 months ago. My concern is that this might end up even being even more fragile in case Apple decides to change some internals.
- [xcpretty](https://github.com/xcpretty/xcpretty): The top dog that is widely recommended and referenced. Unfortunately, it hasn't been updated in more than two years and [this issue](https://github.com/xcpretty/xcpretty/issues/360) suggests it won't happen in the future. I have also had trouble exporting the test results in JUnit format and error reporting isn't working properly.

All of these export to JUnit format which is then picked up by bamboo, maybe that's not the best choice? Apart from these options are there any alternatives I have missed that export `xcodebuild` test results to bamboo?

Comment: did you find a solution to this?  I could get coverage report data using slather, but what I also want is test pass/fail and reason for failure to be extracted as well

Comment: @MichaelNguyen , the solution we have settled on is the second one. It's not perfect, but good enough to get the test results reliably. It may cease to work one day and not get updated, but that day has not yet come.